# Task is running and cannot be finished

Tags: vb.net

Have strange behaviour in my task which is not finishing. I use this all the time but i suppose its because sub i am passing to it is iteracting with form - changing selection and refreshing some listbox probably therefore its stack there but i am not sure. Lets see the code:

This is the sub i want to be run in task:

```
    Public Sub UnselectExistingConnectionsItems()
        Dim SentenceId, SubSubKategorieId, SubSectionId As Integer
        SubSectionId = CbSubSections.SelectedValue   'combobox
        If WithSubSubkategorie = SubSubKategorieEnum.Without Then
            SubSubKategorieId = 0
        Else
            SubSubKategorieId = CbSubSubKategorie.SelectedValue  'combobox
        End If
Unselect:
        For i As Integer = 0 To LB_Sentences.SelectedItems.Count - 1
            Dim sKey As ListBoxItem
            sKey = LB_Sentences.SelectedItems(i)
            SentenceId = HtmlDescription.HtmlSentence.GetSentenceIdByName(sKey.Text)
            If HtmlDescription.HtmlSubSubSections_Sentences.CheckIfConnectionAlreadyExist(SentenceId, SubSectionId, SubSubKategorieId) Then
                sKey.IsSelected = False
                LB_Sentences.Refresh()
                GoTo Unselect
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

i put it to Task like this:

```
Dim pic As New FrmCircularProgress(eCircularProgressType.Line)
Dim work As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
'--Run lenghty task                                                   UnselectExistingConnectionsItems()
'--Close form once done (on GUI thread)
pic.Invoke(New Action(Sub() pic.StopCircular()))
pic.Invoke(New Action(Sub() pic.Close()))
End Sub)

'--Show the form
pic.ShowDialog()
Task.WaitAll(work)
```

and FrmCircularProgress is just form ( i use it almost everywhere where i have to user wait and its working besides this particural case):

```
Public Class FrmCircularProgress
    Sub New(progressType As DevComponents.DotNetBar.eCircularProgressType)
        InitializeComponent()
        CircularProgress1.ProgressBarType = progressType
        StartCircular()
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartCircular()
        Me.CircularProgress1.IsRunning = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub StopCircular()
        Me.CircularProgress1.IsRunning = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

what could be wrong? is it because procedure is interacting with listbox and combobxes? If so how to fix that, i read something about invoking listbox and comboboxes but have no idea how to fix that.

**EDIT:**
I think besides those lines:

```
sKey.IsSelected = False
                LB_Sentences.Refresh()
```

I have to make those:

```
  LB_Sentences.Invoke(Sub()  sKey.IsSelected = False
              End Sub)
LB_Sentences.Invoke(Sub()                                                                 LB_Sentences.Refresh()
     End Sub)
```

because i am in diffrent thread. Somehow i dont know how to convert those lines:

```
 SubSectionId = CbSubSections.SelectedValue
  SubSubKategorieId = CbSubSubKategorie.SelectedValue
```

probably loop also have to be invoked. Waiting your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule that says "The only thread that can modify a control in a window is the thread that created the window". Any other thread trying to modify something in the window will generate a cross-thread call exception.

So in your first edit you got it right, you have to invoke the functions.

However, this doesn't fix your problem of not finishing Task.

I believe that doing `sKey.IsSelected = False` does not unselect anything in your ListBox, therefore causing an infinite loop... Also that `Goto` statement is very bad programming habits and should not be used. There is always another solution that will make your code easier to debug/maintain/read...

`ListBoxItem` is not a type that exists in the .Net Framework. So either you created that class either it's something else (and I don't know what...)

What you can do to solve your problem is :

1. Get the indices of all selected items in a list
2. Run through your list, and check if they should be selected :

   - If they should be selected, do nothing
   - if they shouldn't, unselect them.

Which makes your code like this (and you remove that ugly Label and Goto that you don't want in your code)...

```
Public Sub UnselectExistingConnectionsItems()
    Dim SentenceId, SubSubKategorieId, SubSectionId As Integer
    SubSectionId = CbSubSections.SelectedValue   'combobox
    If WithSubSubkategorie = SubSubKategorieEnum.Without Then
        SubSubKategorieId = 0
    Else
        SubSubKategorieId = CbSubSubKategorie.SelectedValue  'combobox
    End If

    'We create an array to remind our initial selection
    Dim sel = New Integer(LB_Sentences.SelectedItems.Count - 1) {}
    LB_Sentences.SelectedIndices.CopyTo(sel, 0)

    For i = 0 To sel.Length - 1
        Dim sKey As ListBoxItem
        'We get our selected item
        sKey = LB_Sentences(sel(i))
        SentenceId = HtmlDescription.HtmlSentence.GetSentenceIdByName(sKey.Text)
        If HtmlDescription.HtmlSubSubSections_Sentences.CheckIfConnectionAlreadyExist(SentenceId, SubSectionId, SubSubKategorieId) Then
            'We must remove it from the selection
            LB_Sentences.Invoke(Sub() LB_Sentences.SelectedItems.Remove(sKey))
        End If
    Next
    'We do the Refresh at the end so we gain some process time...
    LB_Sentences.Invoke(Sub() LB_Sentences.Refresh())
End Sub
```